# 'setup' does not name a type?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, timers, events

Was trying to work some code that I found online to suit my needs and it continues to show the same error **'setup' does not name a type**. I have tried setting it to void, Void as well as rewriting the code but still the same issue arises and I was wondering how to fix this issue.

This program will at some point compile data from 3 different sensors and do its various calculations within these separate loops and print to serial in a table that can then be saved or exported. The only sensor attached at the moment is a ultrasonic sensor that measures the distance it is from a surface. (last 2 groups of code have a basic print function just so the loop is occupied)

Here is the code:

```
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>

long timeCounter; // milliseconds counter  
long timePassed; // The actual milliseconds time 
int trigPin = 2;
int echoPin = 3; 

long delay1 = 10;    // ms for cycle of event 1  
long delay2 = 5;     // ms for cycle of event 2  
long delay3 = 25;    // ms for cycle of event 3  
long delay4 = 10;

// Counters for the number of triggered events before the  
// corresponding event starts  
int countEvent1, countEvent2, countEvent3, countEvent4;  

int TRIGGER = 5; // ms to trigger the milliseconds timer  

int MAX1 = 2; // Number or triggered milliseconds to start event1  
int MAX2 = 1; // Number or triggered milliseconds to start event2  
int MAX3 = 5; // Number or triggered milliseconds to start event3  
int MAX4 = 2;

// Initialisation  
setup {  
     timeCounter = millis(); // read the actual internal time  
     timePassed = 0; // we start with no time passed  

     countEvent1 = 0;  
     countEvent2 = 0;  
     countEvent3 = 0;
     countEvent4 = 0; 
} 

// Infinite cycle  
loop() {  

     // Read the actual time  
     timePassed = millis() - timeCounter;  
     // The smallest unit of time that should trigger an event is for event 2 (5 ms)  
     // so our trigger should count this smaller unit  

     // Check if the time passed after last reading is the trigger time  
     if(timePassed >= TRIGGER) {   
          if(++countEvent1 == MAX1){  
               // Reset the trigger and start the event  
               event1();  
               countEvent1 = 0;  
          } // Event 1   

          // It's time to manage the events  
          if(++countEvent2 == MAX2){  
               // Reset the trigger and start the event  
               event2();  
               countEvent2 = 0;  
          } // Event2 

          // It's time to manage the events  
          if(++countEvent3 == MAX3){  
               // Reset the trigger and start the event  
               event3();  
               countEvent3 = 0;  
          } // Event3

          if(++countEvent4 == MAX4){  
               // Reset the trigger and start the event  
               event4();  
               countEvent4 = 0;  
          } // Event4 

     } // Trigger 

} // LOOP  

// ============ Event functions ============== 

event1() {  
  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin,HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration=pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance =(duration/2)/29.1;
}  

event2() {  
Serial.print("work")
}  

event3() {   
Serial.print("work")
}
```

I am very new to coding so there will be stupid mistakes hidden amongst this I can guarantee it.

Comment: You're just forgetting the smooth brackets after `void setup`. It should be `void setup () {`

Comment: You should learn the basics of a language's syntax before writing programs in it...

Answer (score 3):

All your functions (including setup and loop) need a type as part of the declaration. This for example:

```
event2() {  
Serial.print("work")
}
```

Should be:

```
void event2() {  
  Serial.print("work");
  }
```

Note also the semicolon after the `Serial.print` function call.

I have [a page that explains the basics](https://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=13900).

On that page is a diagram that breaks down what a function declaration looks like:

[image: Function definitions]

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with function definition. Let me explain with an example.

```
int kPinLed = 8; // LED - Pin 8

void setup()
{
  pinMode(kPinLed, OUTPUT); // LED as output
}

void loop()
{
  ledFun(); //Create LED Function
}

//Now write function's code with type, here "void"

void ledFun()
{
  digitalWrite(kPinLed, HIGH); //LED ON
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(kPinLed, LOW);  //LED OFF
  delay(1000);
}
```

Same things you have to do with your code. Just write properly function's type. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Function declarations start with a type:

```
void setup() {

}

void loop() {

}
```

void means the function doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you never defined setup or loop which need the void before them.

```
void setup(){

}



void loop(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> error 'setup' does not name a type. I have tried setting it to void

the correct typing of it is this:

```
void setup(void) {
...
}

void loop(void) {
...
}
```